# What is the process to create new version of apk with minor changes after beta testing

Tags: android

I have deployed my app for beta testing and made some updates to app. I want to know versioning process and creating signed apk for updated app. What are the significance of keystore which I created during ininitail version of app.

Answer (score 0):

The keystore/key is how the Android system knows that it's *you* who made the updates and not some malicious trickster. You need to sign the next release APK with the same key in order for the app to be updated. If you lost the key or want to use a new one, then you'll force your users to uninstall the previous app before installing the new one. Otherwise they will not be able to use the updated app.